# Is it wise to use HTTPSession in spring web app to store object data that will be displayed in multiple jsp pages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, httpsession

I am currently working on a spring boot web application project.

We have a table which contains all the store information, such as current address, previous address and other store info.

In our frontend view we have four jsp pages: 
One page which contains all the store information and the other three will contain current address, previous address and other store info, respectively.

I was thinking to retrieve the store information only once and that is on the main page, where all store information is displayed. Then, I'll just save the store information to a session attribute, so that I can just access it on the other pages which will contain just the same information, instead of retrieving it multiple times from the repository.

Would that be a wise move? 
... Or is using HTTPSession inefficient in this case?

I hope someone could give me their insight on this as i am really new to this whole spring boot web application development thing. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is this data you intent to store meant for every user on the application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `HTTPSession`? Do you mean as session cookie in the browser or in the session context within  spring?

Comment: The HTTPSession which is passed as method argument in the controller

Comment: The data is only meant for particular user only

Comment: Session is a container that expires. Also you must think about how to refresh the values when repository has been updated. By the way this kind of question is hard to answer because you are asking of opinion ;-)

Comment: Is it better to just call the repository everytime the different pages are accessed even though its just the same data?